# Is there a way to tell if a shorcode's handler is being run before or after the content formatting filter?

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode, api

Apparently (based on what I observe) WordPress runs every shortcode handler *twice* for every time that shortcode appears --- once, preliminarily, before the output is processed (and the output of the shortcode processing is apparently thrown away at this point) and another time after the output is processed (which is the time that the output actually gets used).

I have no idea *why* WordPress does it (just that it *does* for *whatever* reason do this) but that's not my question.

My question is this --- is there anything in the WordPress API that will allow a shortcode's handler to detect whether it is being invoked during the preliminary round or in the round that actually counts?

This is important because I am attempting to implement a ShortCode that would be sensitive to how many times it gets invoked. It is important for me to do this, and I need to know how to detect this quirk of WordPress so that the shortcode can avoid counting the repetitions who's return value doesn't even get displayed in a way that affects the repetitions who's outputs *do* get displayed.

Comment: to the best of my knowledge shortcodes are run only once. do you have a citation or code sample that shows it is run twice? But in general if the shortcode is sensative to the number of times it is invoked then you are probably doing it wrong.

Comment: @MarkKaplun writes "if the shortcode is sensative to the number of times it is invoked then you are probably doing it wrong." -- but honestly, I have no idea how to do what I need to do without using shortcodes, and without them being sensitive to how many times they run. I'd explain what exactly it _is_ that I am trying to do - but the character limit in these comments is way too small for that. At any rate - I can think of no way to achieve my purposes _without_ using shortcodes _or_ without them keeping count of how many times they are run.

Comment: @MarkKaplun - I think I have a solution. I am adding a filter to the 'the_content' hook that will insert a unique ID-field into every instance of this shortcode. Now, the shortcode handler will only do it's think if the ID-field exists. If the value of the ID-field is the same as the value it had on a previous run, it will simply repeat the output it gave on that previous run (rather than generating a new output).

Comment: You can have a global/static variable that counts the number of times the shortcode was invoke to fix the original issue, but really a shortcode should return always the same output for the same input, otherwise if you expect something to happen on every page view then any sort of page based caching will make your code to fail.

Comment: @MarkKaplun --- how exactly will page-based caching make my code fail? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: if you return different results for different invocations in time of the shortcode then one of them, when cached, is the wrong one for the time a page is viewed.

Comment: @MarkKaplun wrote "if you return different results for different invocations in time of the shortcode then one of them, when cached, is the wrong one for the time a page is viewed." -- Generally a sensible concern - however, not necessarily so in the case of what I am doing this for. If someone caches the same URL twice, the only way the output of this shortcode will change is if either (a) I alter it's resource-tree between the two invocations (a concern that applies equally to any content - shortcode or otherwise) or <continued-in-next-comment>

Comment: @MarkKaplun <continued-from-previous-comment> if (b) the person doing the caching switches from a mobile browser to a desktop browser or the reverse. Even if I _do_ add a feature of deliberate randomness (which I haven't decided on) that feature will (a) only be used if the admin specifically codes the resource-tree to do so and (b) will not be the kind of content for which any of the possible outputs is "wrong".

Comment: @MarkKaplun - The kind of stuff this shortcode outputs, if this were for a blog, I'd trust one of the several plugins already available to auto-detect places in the post to insert the kind of code this shortcode outputs. However, my WordPress is used for a WebFiction, and it is therefore far more essential that the places where this code is inserted are chosen with the sensibility that only a human being can apply. Also, in a web-fiction (unlike a blog) it is *vital* that when the readers reach an ad, it is made clear to them that it is _not_ necessarily the end of the post.